# How to write a regular expression that only matches strings or variables that starts with +?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches a pattern only if it contains a string or variable name that has the `+` sign before it. 
So, for example, using this text as input:

```
+ "string1" + variable1 +"string2" + variable2
```

I want that the regex to match and return the text. But if the text is in this form:

```
+ "string1" + variable1 error + variable2 ` or `+ "string1" + variable1 +
```

(the string or variable does not have `+` before [first case],  after `+` there is nothing [second case]) I want the regular expression not to match the text and in that way return nothing(null).

I have written this so far 
([Here is a live demo to play with](https://regex101.com/r/yO5iT3/2)):

```
/^ *\+ *("(?:[^"]*)"|(?:[a-zA-Z]\w*)) *(.*)$/
```

However, it only matches if the first part of the text is `+"string"` or `+ variable` even the part after has errors.

Comment: can you give us a couple test strings and what you expect to get as your match? also give use a couple test cases that dont match. It's difficult to understand what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `+ "string"` or `+ var` like substrings 1 or more times by enclosing these patterns into a capturing group and using a `+` quantifier:

```
^(\+\s*(?:"[^"]+"|[a-zA-Z]\w*)\s*)+$
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO5iT3/3)

Note the `m` modifier that will make `^` and `$` match the start and end of lines, not the start and end of the whole string (more for demonstration purposes).

Comment: Oh @stribizhev thanks a lot. You help me again:). I am working on it now

Comment: Ah, never you mind :) I seem to like your questions :)